# how read specific line from csv file in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to read csv file in django but I don't know how to achieve it. I am fresher recently joined organization and working singly, please any one help me

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

import  csv
from csv import reader


def fun(request):
    with open(r"C:\Users\Sagar\Downloads\ULB_Sp_ThreePhaseUpdate.csv") as file:

        reader = csv.reader(file)
        ip = request.GET["id"]
        flag = False
        for rec in reader:
            if rec[1]=="id":
                return HttpResponse("MID: ",rec[2])

        return render(request, "index.html")
```

Comment: What is the problem in given code ?

Comment: If you want to get the data based on `id`, replace `if rec[1]=="id":` with `if rec[1]==ip:`. I am assuming you are getting value of ip

Comment: don't take the same name for variable and function. your `reader ` is in both function and variable.